# Bash Script Quits After Exiting SSH

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm trying to write a Bash script that logs into 2 different linux based power-strips (Ubiquiti Mpower Pros) and turns 2 different lights off (one on each strip). To do this I login to the 1st strip, change the appropriate file to 0 (thus turning off the light), and exit, repeating the same process on the next power-strip. However, after I exit the first SSH connection, the script stops working. Could someone please suggest a fix? My only idea would be to encase this script in a python program. Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh User@192.168.0.100
echo "0" > /proc/power/relay1
exit
# hits the enter key
cat <(echo "") | <command>

ssh User@192.168.0.103
echo "logged in"
echo "0" > /proc/power/relay1
exit
cat <(echo "") | <command>
```

Comment: The 'exit' line is breaking it for you.  This would be more easily done with expect scripting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ssh` as an app BLOCKS while it's running,  the `echo` and `exit` are executed by the local shell, not by the remote machine. so you are doing:

1. ssh to remote machine
2. exit remote shell
3. echo locally
4. exit locally

and boom, your script is dead. If that echo/exit is supposed to be run on the remote system, then you should be doing:

```
ssh user@host command
               ^^^^^---executed on the remote machine
```

e.g.

```
ssh foo@bar 'echo ... ; exit'
```

Answer (score 2):

The commands you're apparently trying to run through `ssh` are actually being executed locally.  You can just pass the command you want to run to ssh and it will do it (without needing an explicit `exit`)

```
ssh User@192.168.0.110 'echo "0" > /proc/power/relay1'
```

will do that, and similar for the other ssh command